# Can go build tell me which file is causing reference to a package?

Tags: go, webassembly, go-modules

Somewhere, deep in some file, are references to these two packages:

```
# github.com/cheggaaa/pb/v3/termutil
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cheggaaa/pb/v3@v3.0.1/termutil/term.go:23:11: undefined: lockEcho
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cheggaaa/pb/v3@v3.0.1/termutil/term.go:39:11: undefined: unlockEcho
# github.com/pkg/term/termios
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/pkg/term@v0.0.0-20190109203006-aa71e9d9e942/termios/ioctl.go:8:33: undefined: syscall.SYS_IOCTL
```

And they are failing when I try and compile with `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o wasm_wrapper.wasm`

I'm finding file after file where I need to add `+// +build !wasm`. Is there anyway for go build (maybe with extra -vvv option?) to tell me which file is referencing these?

Comment: No. But `go mod why` at least gives you a path through the package import graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
// +build !wasm

package foo
```

is different than

```
// +build !wasm
package foo
```

My issue was I was still getting those errors because I was missing the newline.